# Create SQL Server "creator" account which cannot view or delete data

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-permissions

Good afternoon, I am looking to see if anyone knows if there is a way to create a "creator" user in SQL. Yes this is Microsoft SQL Server.

I would like this user to be able to:

- Create objects (functions, stored procedures, tables, views)
- Insert data as needed

I would like this user to NOT be able to:

- View or delete any data.

Any input would be appreciated, doing testing now.

I will try the db_denydatareader - and this account will be used by an automated process only, we simply want to deny reader as it's not needed and in-case the user was compromised.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tough one...
First of all, I am assuming Microsoft SQL server.

Read this:
[Permissions (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can try db_owner and and db_denydatareader on the user, since you are testing now. It is a long shot. But even if it works, the user might then change data and it looses its integrety.